# C++ program giving -2147483648 output

Tags: c++, output

I am developing a program where the user inputs certain data about his daily life, and the things he has to do, along with a priority level for them. I have made an algoritham to figure this out but when executing it I get some weird output. I have inlcuded the program and output below (I know the program is rudimentery):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int bodyProgram()
{
 int A;
cout << "How many activities do you have per weekday this week?: ";
cin >> A;

string NumActivities[7][2] =
{
    {
        "How much time do you spend per meal?:",
        "How many meals do you have per day?:",
    },
    {
        "How much time do you spend in the bathroom? (Excluding taking a pee):",
        "How many times do you go to the bathroom per day?:",
    },
    {
        "When do you wake up?(ex. 7:00am should be typed as 07 00): ",
    },
    {
        "How many naps do you take per day?(Enter 0 if none):",
        "How long per nap?(0 if none):",
    },
    {
        "Do you take any breaks, excluding meals? (Enter 0 if none):",
        "How long per break?(0 if none):",
    },
    {
        "How much time do you spend at work or school? (H:M ex. 7 hours and 10 minutes is 7 10):",
        "How much time do you spend commuting each way (In minutes)?:",
    },
    {
        "Enter the name of the activity:",
        "Enter the priority level of the activity from 1-10, 1 being optional and 10 being of utmost importance:",
    },
};

string Name[100];
float Time[6];
float Amount[6];
float NormalSleep;
float NormalSchool;
float Normal;
int priority[100];

cout << "Please enter all information in minutes unless specified\n";

for (int i=0; i<=6; i++)
{
    if (i==2)
    {
        float SleepH;
        float SleepM;

        cout << NumActivities[2][0];
        cin >> SleepH >> SleepM;
        cin.clear();

           float F;
           F = SleepM/60;

           float total;
           total= SleepH +F;

        NormalSleep = total;


    }

    else if (i==5)

    {
        float SH;
        float SM;
        float com;

        cout << NumActivities[5][0];
        cin >> SH >> SM;

        cout << NumActivities[5][1];
        cin >> com;

        if ((SH==0) && (SM==0) && (com))
        {
            continue;
        }

        float SF;
        SF=SM/60;

        float SchoolTime;
        SchoolTime=SH+SF;

        float ComTotal;
        ComTotal=com * 2;

        float ComDiv;
        ComDiv=ComTotal/60;

        float Total;
        Total=SchoolTime+ComDiv;

        float TotalDiv;
        TotalDiv=Total/60;

        NormalSchool=TotalDiv;


    }

    else if (i>5)

    {
        for (int f=0; f<A; f++)
        {
            int TPri;
            TPri=i-6;

            cout << NumActivities[6][0];
            cin >> Name[i];

            cout << NumActivities[6][1];
            cin >> priority[TPri];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout << NumActivities[i][0];
        cin >> Time[i];

        cout << NumActivities[i][1];
        cin >> Amount[i];

        float AcT;
        AcT= Time[i]*Amount[i];

        float Hours;
        Hours = AcT/60;

        Normal=Normal+Hours;
    }

    }

    float NormalAdd;
    NormalAdd=Normal+NormalSchool+NormalSleep;




    int NormalND;
    NormalND=NormalAdd;

    float NormalDec;
    NormalDec = NormalAdd-NormalND;

    int NormalTime;
    NormalTime=NormalDec*60;

    cout <<NormalND<<" hours and "<<NormalTime<< " minutes\n";

    float FACTime[50];

    float Left;
    Left=24-Normal;

    float Alloc;
    Alloc=Left/A;

    float Allpri110;
    Allpri110=Alloc*5;

    float Allpri29;
    Allpri29=Alloc*4;

    float Allpri38;
    Allpri38=Alloc*3;

    float Allpri47;
    Allpri47=Alloc*2;

    float Allpri6;
    Allpri6=Alloc*1.2;

    for (int i=0; i<=A; i++)
    {
        if (priority[i]==1)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc-Allpri110;
        }

        if (priority[i]==2)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc-Allpri29;
        }

        if (priority[i]==3)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc-Allpri38;
        }

        if (priority[i]==4)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc-Allpri47;
        }

        if (priority[i]==5)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc;
        }

        if (priority[i]==6)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc+Allpri6;
        }

        if (priority[i]==7)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc+Allpri47;
        }

        if (priority[i]==8)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc+Allpri38;
        }

        if (priority[i]==9)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc+Allpri29;
        }

        if (priority[i]==10)
        {
            FACTime[i]=Alloc+Allpri110;
        }
    }


    int FTimeND;
    FTimeND = FACTime[2];

    float FTimeDec;
    FTimeDec = FACTime[2]-FTimeND;

    int FTime;
    FTime = FTimeDec*60;

     cout <<FTimeND<<" hours and "<<FTime<< " minutes\n";


return 0;
}






int main()
{
 bodyProgram();
 return 0;
}
```

The intended output for this is:

```
'How many activities do you have per weekday this week?: 2
Please enter all information in minutes unless specified
How much time do you spend per meal?:15
How many meals do you have per day?:2
How much time do you spend in the bathroom? (Excluding taking a pee):30
How many times do you go to the bathroom per day?:2
When do you wake up?(ex. 7:00am should be typed as 07 00): 08 45
How many naps do you take per day?(Enter 0 if none):0
How long per nap?(0 if none):0
Do you take any breaks, excluding meals? (Enter 0 if none):0
How long per break?(0 if none):0
How much time do you spend at work or school? (H:M ex. 7 hours and 10        minutes is 7 10):7 00
How much time do you spend commuting each way (In minutes)?:30
Enter the name of the activity:AC1
Enter the priority level of the activity from 1-10, 1 being optional:1         
Enter the name of the activity:AC2
Enter the priority level of the activity from 1-10, 1 being optional:6
10 hours and 22 minute
x hours and x minutes'
```

However this is the output I get:

```
'How many activities do you have per weekday this week?: 2
Please enter all information in minutes unless specified
How much time do you spend per meal?:15
How many meals do you have per day?:2
How much time do you spend in the bathroom? (Excluding taking a pee):30
How many times do you go to the bathroom per day?:2
When do you wake up?(ex. 7:00am should be typed as 07 00): 08 45
How many naps do you take per day?(Enter 0 if none):0
How long per nap?(0 if none):0
Do you take any breaks, excluding meals? (Enter 0 if none):0
How long per break?(0 if none):0
How much time do you spend at work or school? (H:M ex. 7 hours and 10        minutes is 7 10):7 00
How much time do you spend commuting each way (In minutes)?:30
Enter the name of the activity:AC1
Enter the priority level of the activity from 1-10, 1 being optional:1         
Enter the name of the activity:AC2
Enter the priority level of the activity from 1-10, 1 being optional:6
-2147483648 hours and -2147483648 minute
-2147483648 hours and -2147483648 minutes'
```

This error only happens when I ask the program to output the second value in the array FACTime and convert it into hours and minutes with the following bit of code:

```
    int FTimeND;
    FTimeND = FACTime[2];

    float FTimeDec;
    FTimeDec = FACTime[2]-FTimeND;

    int FTime;
    FTime = FTimeDec*60;

     cout <<FTimeND<<" hours and "<<FTime<< " minutes\n";
```

I am unable to find a solution for this and even converting the output of -2147483648 into hex doesn't help. If I take away the code it outputs everything fine but with it it outputs that. All help is appreciated.

Comment: @Axalo I forgot to mention that my input is inlcuded in the output. Just look beside the prompt for my input.

Comment: The last part doesn't make sense at all. Shouldn't `FACTime[2]-FTimeND` always result in 0 as both of the operands are equal?

Comment: you should initialize you variables and arrays.

Comment: I think you haven't noticed that `-2147483648` is a very special number - the lowest value that can be stored by a 32-bit `int`. Its binary representation in 2's complement is a `1` followed by 31 `0`s. So many `0`s are a hint that you are dealing with an uninitialised variable, that takes the value that it already had, which for some reason happened to be that. So you should check that all your variables have been properly initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FACTime[2]` is never initialized and neither is most of `priority[]`.

In your first loop, you set `priority[TPri]` only if i > 5, and you set `TPri=i-6` which can therefore only be 0. So priority[0] is set, but nothing else. In your second loop, `FACTime[2]` is set only if `priority[2]` evaluates to something in your if/else blocks, but it doesn't because `priority[2]` is uninitialized.

If each element in the priority array is intended to correspond to a single activity as entered by the user, you probably wanted something like:

```
for (int f=0; f<A; f++)
{
    cout << NumActivities[6][0];
    cin >> Name[f];

    cout << NumActivities[6][1];
    cin >> priority[f];
}
```

Comment: I see, I apoligize for that elementary mistake. I didn't think that not initializing it would cause that since all my previous porgrams didn't do this. Thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: Ok, new problem. The intended output for the program is 6.35 or so, I get 24.75.

Comment: The fact that you are accessing uninitialized values is just a symptom. Your iterations shouldn't have you accessing those values in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing `Normal` is being used without being initialized, so that's probably the problem with your first output line.

But the real problem seems to be with priority. It's containing only 1 item, but your for loop at the end is running 3 times.